# WPF converter for ObservableCollection combined with static items

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection, ivalueconverter

I am trying to bind `ComboBox` to an `ObservableCollection` which will have some static items as the first items and then the actual items from the collection.

```
No index
1% p.a.
5% p.a.
--------
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

I think a binding converter could do the trick.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource = "{Binding indexes}, Converter={StaticResource IndexCollectionConverter}}" />
```

The collection where items are added and deleted at runtime.

```
public virtual ObservableCollection<indexation> indexes{ get; set; }
```

I need to always have some static items (first 3 items), then a separator (optional but nice if possible) and then all the items from the actual `ObservableCollection`.

I am aware of the [CompositeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class but Visual Studio output window gives me a binding error when implemented in `XAML`.

So I tried the converter but I got lost how to return this kind of collection from the convert method.

```
public class IndexCollectionConverter: IValueConverter {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //LOST HERE...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How should the converter be defined to return the collection?

Comment: Why not just populate the static items in code? Create your indexes ObservableCollection, populate it with the static items and then add the runtime loaded items.

Answer (score 0):

Try an IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class IndexCollectionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values                               // loop through all values
            .Select(v => v as IEnumerable<object>)  // cast to something we can enumerate
            .Where(v => v != null)                  // ignore anything we can't
            .SelectMany(v => v)                     // concat them all into a single list
            .ToList();                              // turn into a memory array now
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here's some sample code, I'm using XmlDataProviders just to show it working but you can change your source bindings to anything:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <local:IndexCollectionConverter x:Key="IndexCollectionConverter" />

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="StaticIndexes">
        <x:XData>
            <IndexData xmlns="">
                <Item Desc="No Index" />
                <Item Desc="1% p.a." />
                <Item Desc="2% p.a." />
            </IndexData>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="DynamicIndexes">
        <x:XData>
            <IndexData xmlns="">
                <Item Desc="Item1" />
                <Item Desc="Item2" />
                <Item Desc="Item3" />
            </IndexData>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>

</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" IsDropDownOpen="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IndexCollectionConverter}">
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource StaticIndexes}" XPath="IndexData/Item" />
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource DynamicIndexes}" XPath="IndexData/Item" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Desc}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Result:

[image]